# How to pass javascript variable into another place?

Tags: javascript

hello i am trying to pass javascript var can anyone explain how to do it ..?

```
<div id="res">
<script>
var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("x");
console.log(c);
adUnit   = document.getElementById("res");
adUnit.innerHTML = '<ins ve-id="how to pass var c here..?"></ins>';
</script>
<script  src="//net.my.com/js.php"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail?

Comment: i am trying to pass var c in to adUnit.innerHTML = '<ins ve-id="how to pass var c here..?"></ins>';

Comment: adUnit.innerHTML = '<ins ve-id=' + c + '></ins>';

Comment: You should read the documentation on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below

```
adUnit.innerHTML = '<ins ve-id="' + c + '"></ins>';
```

In ES6 version

```
adUnit.innerHTML = `<ins ve-id="${c}"></ins>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```js
<div id="res">
<script>
  var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var c = url.searchParams.get("x");
  console.log(c);
  adUnit   = document.getElementById("res");
  adUnit.innerHTML = '<ins ve-id="' + c + '"></ins>';
</script>
<script  src="//net.my.com/js.php"></script>
```

You can also take a look on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
  adUnit.innerHTML = `<ins ve-id="${c}"></ins>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interpolate string.

So, do something like

adUnit.innerHTML = `<ins ve-id=4{c}></ins>`;